# Collecting data from a Chinese website using selenium

Tags: parsing, selenium-webdriver, encoding, cjk

I'm in the business of collecting data from the site https://m.guazi.com/detail?clueId=129125011 with Selenium and I have encountered this problem, in the tag with the cost of the car I see some strange symbols

```
<span class="price-num gzfont" data-v-68ea11d6="">.万</span>
```

At the same time, everything looks normal on the page itself in the browser

[image: everything looks fine in the picture]

Here's my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from chromedriver_py import binary_path
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

svc = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=binary_path)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.5845.888 YaBrowser/23.9.2.888 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=svc, options=options)

url = "https://www.guazi.com/buy"

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[10]")
    element.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[11]")
    element.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "car-card.content-item")
    element.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(5)
    element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pageWrapper > div.pc-detail > div.center.js-center.detail > div.infor-main.clearfix.service-open > div.product-textbox > div.pricebox.js-disprice > div.price-main > span")
    price = element.text
    print(price)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)

finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Can you tell me what the problem may be related to? Is it related to UTF-8 encoding? Or is it some tricky encryption from the developers?
This problem affects not only the cost, but all other numbers in the car card (release date, mileage, etc.).

P.S..
When I tried to open the page in Firefox, I noticed that in place of the cost for a fraction of a second there were these symbols.
[image: in Firefox]

I wanted to get the car value data and save it to a json dictionary, but what I see is not numbers but some obscure characters

Comment: Actually, that is not an English word/number so the code is never understood. One thing you can do here is get the text and store it in the string and use any translator it can translate the Chinese number to a common number, after converting you can store the number in JSON.